# Nested For commands in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a simple batch file that will individually compress "rar" each file in the source directory. Naming of the rar files should be based on the date/time of file creation.

Having difficulties getting the names to reflect the accurate date/time. Currently all rar files created bear the same name. Think problem has to do with the use of nested FOR commands

Newbie here. Would appreciate help if possible.

```
setlocal
set _source=H:\Test
set _dest=J:\output

for /f "delims=/ tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%DATE:~4%") do (
        for /f "delims=:. tokens=1-4" %%m in ("%TIME: =0%") do (
            set _FILENAME=basename%%c%%b%%a%%m%%n%%o%%p
        )
    )

ECHO %_FILENAME%

for %%I in (%_source%\*.*) DO (

md "%_dest%\%%~nI"
"rar.exe" A -v50M -m0 -k -y -ep1 -r -t -hp[aabbcc] "%_dest%\%%~nI\%_FILENAME%.rar" "%_source%\%%~nxI"
phpar2.exe c -s640000 -r10 -l "%_dest%\%%~nI\%_FILENAME%.par2" "%_dest%\%%~nI\%_FILENAME%*.rar"

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "_source=H:\Test"
set "_dest=J:\output"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%I in (%_source%\*.*) DO (
    for /f "delims=/ tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%DATE:~4%") do (
        for /f "delims=:. tokens=1-4" %%m in ("!TIME: =0!") do (
            set _FILENAME=basename%%c%%b%%a%%m%%n%%o%%p
            ECHO !_FILENAME!
        )
    )
    md "%_dest%\%%~nI"
    "rar.exe" A -v50M -m0 -k -y -ep1 -r -t -hp[aabbcc] "%_dest%\%%~nI\!_FILENAME!.rar" "%_source%\%%~nxI"
     phpar2.exe c -s640000 -r10 -l "%_dest%\%%~nI\!_FILENAME!.par2" "%_dest%\%%~nI\!_FILENAME!*.rar"
)

endlocaL
endlocal
```

Is this what you want?
You can nest the three loops but to use _FILENAME you'll need [delayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: That's not really what I trying to do. I'm trying to nest the _FILENAME loop within the %%I loop (i.e. every time it goes through each file in source directory, it will be assigned a new unique filename tied to date and time.

Comment: @David aaah!Just give me a moment.

Comment: Tried the revised scrip. not sure why but for each iteration, the ECHO !_FILENAME! still prints the same result.

Comment: @David - edited again .TIME variable (if you want also the DATE) should be accessed with delayed expansion (`!` instead of `%`)

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what I wanted. Many thanks for your help. Learnt quite a bit today